# Make client browser load page and inject js after

Tags: javascript, browser, client, headless-browser

I need to implement a service:

1. Client enters some third party URI into a form on my web-site.
2. My server sends client a js script of this nature: 
   ***"download entered URI, render it, inject js code 'X' into rendered DOM"***

What it does is basically making a browser agnostic browser-extension. :)

Is there a name for such a thing? I've heard that modern web-sites do smth of this sort: they don't send html to client, but some js script instead, which makes client browser download futher js and html ect.

Comment: 2) is impossible. You have to do that at the serverside, and send the prepared htnl to the client.

Comment: I do exactly it, but was looking for more ways to implement such a thing.

Comment: xss but browsers/pages actively do things to prevent this. Server-side or Plugin and your only real options.